# How to use `vars` in `secretGenerator`?

Tags: kubernetes

In my `kustomization.yaml` file I'm trying:

```yaml
secretGenerator:
  - name: app-env
    behavior: merge
    envs:
      - app.env
    literals:
      - DB_HOST=$(DB_HOST)
vars:
  - name: DB_HOST
    objref:
      kind: Service
      name: mariadb-service
      apiVersion: v1
    fieldref:
      fieldpath: metadata.name
```

But the environment variable `DB_HOST` is coming out as the string literal `$(DB_HOST)` instead of being replaced with the service name, like I want.

How can I get the name of my service into that env var?

Comment: Literals literally means literal values. AFAIK no variable substitution is done. Of course it doesn't make sense to make a DB_HOST a secret anyway...

Comment: It's kind of annoying to split my env vars into secrets and non-secrets. My app (laravel) was previously set up to use a single .env file with the hosts and passwords and everything in one. Plus, if I do that, then I have to update a dozen Kubernetes YAML files to double up all the `envFrom`s. Regardless, ConfigMaps have the same issue, no?

Comment: Would you consider posting your question in stackoverflow.com instead? Server Fault is more about underlying host issues, posting this kind of question in Stack will surely allow you to get more advices from the community.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe I'll ask it over there....last time I asked a Kubernetes question there, they sent me over here, so I really don't know where I'm supposed to ask about server technologies. It sure sounds like it's it's on point according to https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic ("managing software of servers", "tools for automating these", "deployment")

Comment: Yes, Kubernetes questions can be asked in both stack forums, I just suggested you to ask on stack overflow because here in kubernetes there is 1.1k questions with this flag while kubernetes tag in stack has 29.1k questions.
Related to your question "from literals" will never process the value as it's declared to use the literal value as the environment variables. Have you tried any variations of this command?

Comment: I think it can done if I put it in the .env file itself and a configuration so kustomize will replace varReferences in files (docs for this are a little buried). I ended up just hardcoding the hostnames because it's too much of a headache